# Why does Rambam not learn the prohibition for adultery from Yitro but from Acharei Mot?

Tags: rambam, mitzvah, parashas-yisro, aseres-hadibros, parshat-acharei-mot

Yitro contains 16 mitzvos according to Rambam. Most of them are linked to the 10 commandments but notably one commandment is missing: adultery.

Instead he learns this prohibition from Acharei Mot:

`Mitzvah #160: Not to have sexual relations with someone else's wife Lev. 18:20`

So, then what does he learn from the commandment in Yitro?

Comment: Where does it say adultery in Yitro?

Comment: 10 commandments are recited in Yitro and this is one of them.

Comment: How do you know this is one of them?

Comment: [Sefer ha-Miswoth NC#347](https://www.sefaria.org/Sefer_HaMitzvot%2C_Negative_Commandments.347.1?lang=bi&with=all&lang2=en) The Rambam cites Ex. 20:13, Lev. 20:10, Lev. 18:6.

Comment: Why should he have preferred the Yitro verse over the Acharei Mot one?

Comment: "Mitzvah #160: Not to have sexual relations with someone else's wife Lev. 18:20" where is this a quote from?

Comment: Theres plenty of evidence that  נאף refers to adultery, see https://mg.alhatorah.org/Dictionary/5003. The Yisro verse ostensibly is to be preferred as the primary source as it appears in the decalogue. @Deuteronomy Had the same q but he is correct that Maimonides cites it as the primary source

Comment: https://www.sefaria.org.il/Sefer_HaMitzvot%2C_Negative_Commandments.347?lang=bi

Answer (score 2):

In my experience Rambam will always cite the verse that expresses the idea most clearly as the primary source. That is not to say that the yisro commandment isnt referring to adultery and doesnt count as a second lav it is just that when sourcing a commandment Rambam will cite the verse that articulates the idea least ambiguously even if Chazal employ a different one as the primary source

(Rambam [writes explicitly](https://www.chabad.org/library/article_cdo/aid/961957/jewish/Negative-Commandment-347.htm) that the yisro verse also refers to adultery and that the Rabbis chose to use it as it can be read as referring to both genders vs the leviticus verse that is gender specific)